# React's component hierarchy makes it awkward to re-arrange tags. Is there a remedy?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-wildflower-n7phj?file=/src/App.js:208-274) is a sandbox of the code below

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Child from "./Child.js";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Child />
      <div class="outsider">I am an outsider. I want to be in in-group</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Child({ givenColor }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="independent">I DO NOT want to be in in-group</div>
      <div className="in-group">I am in in-group</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Without React, it'd be simple enough to change the html to place `.outsider` in `.in-group`. With React, I don't know if I can do this. Can I?

*Solutions:*

1. I know I could put `.outsider` in `Child` but, in my real project, i) semantically, it doesn't make sense & ii) it'd involve reorganising components to pass functions as props from `App` to `Child` to be used by `.outsider`. This is possible but a pain.
2. If there's no clever way to solve this, I'd rather manually move `.outsider` into `.in-group` with vanilla JS. Does anyone forecast any problems doing that?

Comment: Any reason to not nest the `.outsider` div as a child component of the `Child` component?  Then render the `children` prop of the `Child` component right in the `.in-group` div? E.g., `<Child><div class="outsider">I am an outsider...</div></Child>`? Is that what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: In case what I said doesn't make sense, this is what I mean: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-agnesi-5pz9g?file=/src/Child.js

Comment: @MarcBaumbach I think that solution will work. I can't think of any reasons why it wouldn't work: i) `.outsider` will have access to everything on the page where it is defined ii) props are updated when component's updated so there won't be any 'stale closures'. I will come back to this question if something unexpected happens. Out of curiosity, do you reckon solution #2 would've worked smoothly? Thank-you btw.

Comment: In a React world, I'd really never recommend moving elements around with vanilla JS. You're at risk disconnecting the hierarchy and causing yourself a lot of pain. There's usually a React-way to accomplish any kind of complex DOM manipulation without having to mess with the DOM yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarcBaumbach's solution worked:

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-agnesi-5pz9g?file=/src/Child.js)

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child.js";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Child>
      <div className="outsider">
        I am an outsider. I want to be in in-group.
      </div>
    </Child>
  );
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Child({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="independent">I DO NOT want to be inside in-group</div>
      <div className="in-group">{children}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React you should (usually) not deal with the DOM at all. You should work with Javascript data and React data handling tools (such as useState), then React creates the DOM-elements.

Then you can move elements from one list to the other, and React renders the result.

E.g.:

```
const outsideElements = [
    { className: 'outsider', text: 'I am an outsider. I want to be in in-group' }
];

const insideElements = [
    { className: 'independent', text: 'I DO NOT want to be in in-group' },
    { className: 'in-group', text: 'I am in in-group' }
]

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Child />
      {
        outsideElements.map( item => <div class={ item.className }>{ item.text }</div> )
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default function Child() {
  return (
    <>
      {
        insideElements.map( item => <div class={ item.className }>{ item.text }</div> )
      }
    </>
  );
}
```